# Callback function using if else plotly dash

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to get the following scenario to work, Using two dropdowns:

- dropdown to select report type (Yearly stats and Recession Stats)
  and dropdown to select the year. Only want the year dropdown to be active when the user selects Yearly stats, otherwise no years are displayed or when Recession stats in selected.

Thank you for your help!

Here is the work in progress code:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1('Automobile Statistics Dashboard 1980 - 2013',
                style={'textAlign': 'center', 'color': '#503D36','font-size': 24}),
        
        html.Div([html.Label('Select Statistics'),
                  dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown-statistics',
                               options=[{'label': 'Yearly Statistics', 'value': 'Yearly Statistics'},
                                        {'label': 'Recession Period Statistics', 'value': 'Recession Period Statistics'}],
                               placeholder='Select a Report',
                               style= {'width': '80%',
                                       'padding': '3px',
                                       'font-size': 20,
                                       'text-Align': 'center'})]),
        
        html.Div([html.Label('Select Year'),
                  dcc.Dropdown(id='select-year',
                               options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in year_list],
                               placeholder='1980',
                               style= {'width': '80%',
                                       'padding': '3px',
                                       'font-size': 20,
                                       'text-Align': 'center'})]),
        html.Div(id='output-container',
                 className='chart-grid',
                 style= {'display': 'flex'}),
    ]
) 

# Define the callback function to update the input container based on the selected statistics
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='select-year', component_property='disabled'),
    Input(component_id='dropdown-statistics',component_property='value'))

def update_input_container(dropdown-statistics):
    if 'dropdown-statistics' =='Yearly Statistics': 
        return False
    else: 
        return True


# Run the Dash app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Stuck on defining the update_input_container....

Answer (score 0):

This works but it relies on the recession dropdown to not have any values from the year dropdown or the statistics dropdown.

```py
import dash
from dash import html, dcc, Output, Input, callback, ALL, MATCH

recession_list = ['recession1', 'recession2']
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1('Automobile Statistics Dashboard 1980 - 2013',
                style={'textAlign': 'center', 'color': '#503D36','font-size': 24}),
        
        html.Div([html.Label('Select Statistics'),
                  dcc.Dropdown(id=dict(type='dropdown', id='statistics-dd'),
                               options=[{'label': 'Yearly Statistics', 'value': 'Yearly Statistics'},
                                        {'label': 'Recession Period Statistics', 'value': 'Recession Period Statistics'}],
                               placeholder='Select a Report',
                               style= {'width': '80%',
                                       'padding': '3px',
                                       'font-size': 20,
                                       'text-Align': 'center'})]),
        
        html.Div([html.Label('Select Year'),
                  dcc.Dropdown(id=dict(type='dropdown', id='year-dd'),
                               options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015]],
                               placeholder='1980',
                               style= {'width': '80%',
                                       'padding': '3px',
                                       'font-size': 20,
                                       'text-Align': 'center'})]),
        
        html.Div([html.Label('Select Recession'),
                  dcc.Dropdown(id=dict(type='dropdown', id='recession-dd'),
                               options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in recession_list],
                               placeholder='Select a recession',
                               style= {'width': '80%',
                                       'padding': '3px',
                                       'font-size': 20,
                                       'text-Align': 'center'})]),
        html.Div(id='output-container',
                 className='chart-grid',
                 style= {'display': 'flex'}),
    ]
) 

# Define the callback function to update the input container based on the selected statistics
@app.callback(
    Output(dict(type='dropdown', id='year-dd'), component_property='disabled'),
    Input(dict(type='dropdown', id='recession-dd'), component_property='value'))

def update_input_container(selected_value):
    return selected_value in recession_list



# Run the Dash app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I'd suggest doing something else, though a bit more complicated. Nest your dropdowns within each other or nest them within an accordion. Check out this page for ideas: https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-do-a-multi-level-dropdowns/34967/6